# Crashes with Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I query a collection for a document that doesn't exist, I'm still returned a non-nil object, which crashes when I try to call `documentSnapshot?.data()`.

The error returned is `"Document '<FSTDocumentKey: XXXXXX>' doesn't exist. Check document.exists to make sure the document exists before calling document.data.'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this can be solved with a nifty little guard statement:

```
guard (documentSnap?.exists ?? false), error == nil else { return }
```

Here's a working example of this check:

```
func getUserData(uid: String, completion: @escaping(([String: Any]?, Error?)) -> ()) {

        let document = defaultStore.collection("user-data").document(uid)

        document.getDocument { (documentSnap, error) in

            guard (documentSnap?.exists ?? false), error == nil else {
                completion((nil, error))
                return
            }

            completion((documentSnap?.data(), error))
}}
```

I don't know why you have to call `.exists()`, and the document isn't just nil, but this is either part of the learning curve, or an artifact of a Beta SDK

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle if there is a snapshot or not.

```
func fetchCity(city: String, completion: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ document: DocumentSnapshot?)->()){
            REF_CITIES.document(city).getDocument { (document, err) in
                if (document?.exists)! {
                    completion(true, document)
                }else {
                    print(err?.localizedDescription)
                    completion(false, nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

You can use .exists only for DocumentSnapshot. You can't use it for QuerySnapshot because QuerySnapshot actually is a multiple DocumentSnapshot.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for posting! What makes me nervous is the force unwrap you have in (document?.exists)! -- Right now their SDK never returns nil (as far as I can tell), but in their documentation it says that it should/will. I'd remove that bang to make that cod more future-proof (which is basically what I tried to do with (documentSnap?.exists ?? false)).

Comment: @MacLean because I haven't check for document?.exists == true, because exists method is a bool getter and it returns true  if the document exists. And force unwrapping it means it definitely will return a Bool val. Whether true or false.

Comment: Force unwrapping is bad practice, especially in this case since it'll crash if the value is nil (which the docs say it should be).

Comment: Actually you are not force unwrapping the documents itself. You are force unwrapping the document parameter which one comes from function